# Error installing mcrypt extension on Centos VPS upgraded to PHP 5.4.33

Tags: centos6, mcrypt, php-5.5

[root@vps-1160435-21941 ~]# yum install php-mcrypt*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.greenmountainaccess.net
 * epel: mirror.clarkson.edu
 * extras: mirror.millry.co
 * updates: mirrors.rit.edu
Setting up Install Process
Examining php-mcrypt-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm: php-mcrypt-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.x86_64
Marking php-mcrypt-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.4.23-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.23-1.el6.remi for package: php-mcrypt-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (/php-mcrypt-5.4.23-1.el6.remi.x86_64)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.23-1.el6.remi
           Installed: php-common-5.4.33-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.33-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5.1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have proper repositories imported into yum, and it is fetching info from built-in list (which contains PHP 5.3.3 in centos 6).

Try following this guide:
https://webtatic.com/packages/php54/

Or this one for latest PHP 5.5
https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/

Comment: You were correct.  I found the ultimate solution at the following URL: http://www.shayanderson.com/linux/centos-5-or-centos-6-upgrade-php-to-php-54-or-php-55.htm